# Triggering windows explorer's "rotate clockwise" operation within a C# application

Tags: c#, windows, image, rotation

I need to rotate an image clockwise only just once after a certain operation. I felt so lazy to include rotating logic to my current image operations class then I come with this idea. What I need is already built within windows explorer, so is it possible to trigger windows explorer's rotate operations within a c# application for a valid file specified?

I have doubts that I can't access to that kind of functionality but I wanted to ask to make sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're better off not relying on the feature since it is not part of the API and can disappear at any time. You should just do your own image rotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to do it with Windows Explorer's integrated photo rotating, but you should check out the awesome image editing/processing library called ImageMagick.  The original API is a native windows (dll) API, but there is a good .NET wrapper that is easy to use.

Here it is:

http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/

There are also wrappers for two dozen or so other languages, linked at ImageMagick's site:
http://www.imagemagick.org/